# How to declare NODE_ENV using .env to webserver?

Tags: webpack, environment-variables, babeljs

I'm having a difficulty of putting the `NODE_ENV` value inside of `.env` then `webserver` to read it.

For file structuring, its like this

```
- utils
  - build.js (https://github.com/lxieyang/chrome-extension-boilerplate-react/blob/master/utils/build.js)
  - env.js (https://github.com/lxieyang/chrome-extension-boilerplate-react/blob/master/utils/env.js)
  - webserver.js (https://github.com/lxieyang/chrome-extension-boilerplate-react/blob/master/utils/webserver.js)
- .env
- webpack.config.js (https://github.com/lxieyang/chrome-extension-boilerplate-react/blob/master/webpack.config.js)
```

What I'd like to do is to declare the `NODE_ENV` value (either production or development) using `.env` or `.env.development`/`.env.production` and not just directly declaring `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'` like in the `webserver.js`

So, for `.env`

```
NODE_ENV=development
BABEL_ENV=development
ASSET_PATH=/
```

Is it possible to do that?

So basically, instead of directly declaring `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'` inside of `webserver.js` and `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'` inside of `build.js`, I'd like them to be declared using `.env` or `.env.development`/`.env.production`.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you might want to look at the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.

You can use the following, most basic example to populate `process.env`:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Comment: I used dotenv webpack and I think it wont read my .env if it is being called in webpack.js

Comment: @user16691768 it's going to use `process.cwd()` by default to resolve the path to your `.env` file. So if you're building your webserver and swapping `.env` files, you'll need to pay attention from where the process is started when running your web server.

Alternatively, if you don't need to swap `.env` files and you're fine with using `EnvironmentPlugin`, you can use `dotenv` in your `webpack.config.js`--in that case you might want to opt for [environment variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) directly, though, seeing as you won't need `dotenv` for the server.